# escape $ in expect script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect << SSHLOGIN

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@$host

expect {
    Password: {
        send "Pass$word\n"
        expect {
            OK: {
                send "xstatus\n"
                send "quit\n"
            }
        }
    }
}
SSHLOGIN
```

It is not able to ssh because it is not escaping the '$' character in "Pass$word\n" since $ is part of the password and there is no variable being passed. How would you escape it? I know in bash, you would add '\', but since the password is in the expect script portion, that does not work.

EDIT:
changing `Pass$word\n` to `Pass\\\$word\n` works

Comment: You can remove one level of escaping if your quote your heredoc: `expect << 'SSHLOGIN'`

Comment: @glennjackman that would also disable expansion of $host in the ssh command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here-documents are bash code, so you'd still use `\$`.

The expect script is TCL, so you'll need to escape the `$` there too. With two levels of escaping, you get:

```
send "Pass\\\$word\n"
```

Comment: I tried using cat, but that did not work. And my final expanded product is a valid except script

Comment: The purpose of `cat` is to write out what expect sees so you can inspect it. It's not supposed to fix the problem by itself. Your expect script is probably not valid, I've updated the answer with what your problem probably is (you haven't given any error messages to help narrow it down).